# How do you access tr when table selector is a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I used to have `$("#results_table tr").remove()`

If I put the table selector in a variable `var table = $("#results_table")`, how do I access `tr`?

`results_table.tr.remove();` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: table.find("tr") ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have jquery object saved in variable, you can use all jquery methods on it directly, example: `table.find("tr").remove()`;

```
var table = $("table")
table.find("tr").remove()
```

```js
var table = $("table")
table.find("tr").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test
      <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
var table = $("table")
table.find("tr").addClass("active")
```

**example:**

```js
var table = $("table")
table.find("tr").addClass("active")
```

```css
.active{
color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test
      <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And if you save it as vanilla JS you can use rows:

```
var table = document.querySelector("table"); 
table.rows[0].remove();
```

```js
var table = document.querySelector("table"); 
table.rows[0].remove();
```

```css
.active{
color:red;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test
      <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have been helpful

```
var x = document.getElementById("results_table");
var y = x.querySelector("tr");
y.remove();
```